# ¿Como usar las teclas de acceso rapido con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, datatables

Me gustaría saber usar las teclas de acceso rapido en Jquery.

Actualmente para los eventos click de un boton se utiliza de esta forma:

```
 $("#id_boton").on('click', function (e) {
 //codigo ...
 });
```

En el caso de la fila de un datatable:

```
$('#idtable tbody').on('click', 'input.elimina_fila', function () {
 //codigo
});
```

pero me gustaría saber por ejemplo cuando presiono la tecla A, y tambien la tecla F1,F2,F3. Pero además, cuando uno presiona la tecla F1, se habre una pestaña del navegador(ayuda), para esos caso, me gustaría saber como bloquear esa acción.

Pero en el caso de la fila de una tabla, como sería. Por ejemplo en la fila de la tabla, hay un input de tipo boton que tiene una clase llamada elimina_fila , en donde en el mismo input, hay un data-valor y en el evento, recibía el valor con this data, así:

```
$('#idtable tbody').on('click', 'input.elimina_fila', function () {
var valor= $(this).data("valor");
```

});

Como lo haría en el caso que me posicionará en la fila de una tabla y despues presionara enter, en donde en el evento, captura los data's??

Me gustaría saber como o que eventos debo usar cuando presiono un boton,y cuando estoy en la fila de un datatable.

Espero poder tener su ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para bloquear la acción de teclas de Acceso rápido como `F1` seria así . variando siempre el KeyCode de la tecla presionada. está página puede ayudar para  [obtener el KeyCode de una tecla](http://keycode.info/)

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keydown', 'body', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode==112){ //F1
            event.preventDefault();
         }
     });
 });
```

Sí desea prevenir más de una tecla , teniendo en cuenta que este ejemplo aplica para el `body` si desea hacerlo en un `input` u otro elemento ,  tendría que modificar indicando el `ID` o la `Clase` especifica.

```
 $(function() {
    $(document).on('keydown', 'body', function(event) {
                    //cambiar body por input.elimina_fila por ejemplo
        var array= [112,113,114,115];//F1,F2,F3,F4
         if(array.includes(event.keyCode)) {
            event.preventDefault();
         }
     });
 });
```

Para un Input de Una tabla sería algo similar

```
$(function() {
    $('#idtable tbody').on('keydown', 'input.elimina_fila', function(event) {
                    //cambiar body por input.elimina_fila por ejemplo
        var array= [112,113,114,115];//F1,F2,F3,F4
         if(array.includes(event.keyCode)) {
            event.preventDefault();
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Bien, pero en el caso de la fila de una tabla, como sería. Por ejemplo en la fila de la tabla, hay un input de tipo boton que tiene una clase llamada elimina_fila , en donde en el mismo input, hay un data-valor y en el evento, recibia el valor con this data, asi:
 $('#idtable tbody').on('click', 'input.elimina_fila', function () {
 var valor= $(this).data("valor");
});
Como lo haría en el caso que me posicionará en la fila de una tabla y despues presionara enter, en donde en el evento, captura los data's??